# What does the phrase "pinging around" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "pinging around" in the following sentence:

**But it’s not only about pinging around a screen in the vain hope you take down another wrestler’s power bar.**

The sentence is from the description of the game The Muscle Hustle. Here is a description of the game from a different source:

You’ve never played a wrestling game like this before! Collect, train, level up and evolve hundreds of wrestlers. Combine the unique stats and abilities of your hyper heroes to build the perfect tag-team for each match and battle it out in extensive single player campaigns or the real-time PvP league.

I got two meanings: "bounce" and "hit". In my opinion, "ping" can be replaced with "hit" here. However, I am waiting for native speakers to confirm this or offer any other insights.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you look up the term "ping"? Pleaee include your research.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I got two meanings: "bounce" and "hit". In my opinion, "ping" can be replaced with "hit" here. However, I am waiting for native speakers to confirm this or offer any other insights.

Comment: The meaning seems pretty clear, the player figuratively  "bounces" around the arena (ring?) searching to grab and/or wrestle their opponent.

Comment: You probably need a gamer to answer this question to your satisfaction. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

I can understand why you might have trouble understanding "pinging" in this context. The closest dictionary definition is:

> Make or cause to make a short, high-pitched ringing sound.

It is most closely associated with the game *ping-pong*, and the sound that the tiny, hollow ball makes striking the table and the paddle. However, by extension, English speakers also use the term "pinging" to describe the *action* of something bouncing off a surface.

One of the very first video games was '*Pong*' - based on the game of *ping-pong*. Many other early video games used the 4 edges of the screen as if they were walls and had objects (sprites) bounce off them. It has become something of a video game trope to say that an object is "pinging around the screen", not just for things that bounce off walls, but any kind of rapid movement.

> But it's not only about pinging around a screen in the vain hope you take down another wrestler's power bar.

Your quote also speaks about the "vanity" of playing a video game, and I get a sense that the term 'pinging around' may be used to reduce the complexity of the video game in question and make it sound more futile.

Answer (score 0):

"Ping" is a computer science term for sending an empty signal that is immediately sent back, usually to measure the quality of the connection. "Pinging" is the sending of such a signal.

A game creator might use this in place of the word "bouncing" as a way emphasize how empty and boring the bouncing is since a computer ping contains no information and is the most basic signal possible.